# Can an Indian citizen holding a valid USA visa visit Colombia without a visa?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, visa-free-entry, colombia

I am planning to travel to Colombia for about a week to attend an academic conference. I am an Indian passport holder currently living in USA with a F-1 visa. Do I need to obtain a visa beforehand from the Colombian consulate?

I have found [two](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=IN&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=CO&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C) [sources](http://www.cancilleria.gov.co/newsroom/news/ciudadanos-chinos-tengan-visado-schengen-o-estados-unidos-no-deberan-tramitar-visa) that claim that Indian citizens holding a valid USA visa are not required to apply for Colombian visa. 
 [[Google Translation]](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cancilleria.gov.co%2Fnewsroom%2Fnews%2Fciudadanos-chinos-tengan-visado-schengen-o-estados-unidos-no-deberan-tramitar-visa&edit-text=)

However, I am not sure if these sources are "official" and trustworthy.Is there a more official source? Also, does this rule apply to "tourists" only? Does anyone have any personal experience with this rule?

Comment: Your source appears to be a Google translation of something from the Colombian government's website. Although that's an unofficial translation, the underlying source is official, no?

Comment: Google translate says that's the case for Chinese citizens, is there another source that says the same about Indian citizens as well?

Comment: @nikhil, the Spanish says "pero también incluye a los ciudadanos indios, tailandeses y vietnamitas", i.e. Indian citizens are also included. This seems to be a government press release. The problem I see is that the KLM Timatic web site doesn't list this exception for Indians (only one for Indians with a green card) so the airlines might not know about it if in fact this is true.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After completing the travel without incident, I can confirm that Indian citizens with a valid non-tourist USA visa are indeed exempted from certain visa requirements to travel to Colombia. I faced no issue at the airport or immigration, as both airport staff and border agents were aware of the rule.

Answer (score 3):

[Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?DE=CO&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=IN&SpecData=1&DE=00&&AR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX#) says that nationals of India don't need a visa if they're holding a visa from a Schengen state (C/D visa) or the United States.

> Visa required, except for Nationals of India with a normal
>   passport and a "C" or "D" visa issued by a Schengen Member
>   State [...]
>   valid for a minimum of 180 days from the
>   arrival date.
>
> Visa required, except for Nationals of India with a normal
>   passport and a visa issued by the USA valid for a minimum of
>   180 days from the arrival date. This does not apply to ''C1''
>   visas. They are visa exempt for a maximum stay of 90 days.

Answer (score 0):

I traveled to Bogotá, Colombia last month, on an India Passport. The immigration officer called her superior, during entry, to check my US H1-B Visa, but he stamped me in immediately.

You can take a print out of [this](http://www.cancilleria.gov.co/newsroom/news/ciudadanos-chinos-tengan-visado-schengen-o-estados-unidos-no-deberan-tramitar-visa) page with you in case of ignorant border officials. Point/underline the 3rd paragraph (in Spanish) on the article.

Answer (score -2):

Seems like you do need a visa, it doesn't matter if you have a visa to stay in USA because what matters is of what country you have a passport: https://colombia.visahq.com/requirements/India/resident-United_States/#!colombia-Tourist-visa

You might contact the US embassy in Colombia just to be sure: https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/country/colombia.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't think that is accurate. Timatic lists a visa exemption for Indian citizens with a US I-551, it just doesn't list an exemption for Indians with other status in the US.