# Indian living in US on H1b travelling to Colombia

Tags: colombia

Can a Indian Citizen living in US with H1b visa stamped, travel to COLOMBIA without getting tourist visa for Colombia stamped? It is a trip on a very short notice

Answer (score 2):

See:[Can an Indian citizen holding a valid USA visa visit Colombia without a visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66057/can-an-indian-citizen-holding-a-valid-usa-visa-visit-colombia-without-a-visa/71285#71285)

> Timatic says that nationals of India don't need a visa if they're
>   holding a visa from a Schengen state (C/D visa) or the United States.
>
> Visa required, except for Nationals of India with a normal passport
>   and a "C" or "D" visa issued by a Schengen Member State [...] valid
>   for a minimum of 180 days from the arrival date.
>
> Visa required, except for Nationals of India with a normal passport
>   and a visa issued by the USA valid for a minimum of 180 days from the
>   arrival date. This does not apply to ''C1'' visas. They are visa
>   exempt for a maximum stay of 90 days.